# Why won't community posts show up?

Tags: google-plus-communities

I joined 2 Google+ photo communities and made 2 posts with photos. I can see them on the community page and my profile, but other people don't see them on the community page. Also, when logged out, I don't see my posts on the community pages either.
I used to post very often and I gained 150 followers from posting so much. I could post pictures fine one minute, then 15 minutes later, none of the posts could be seen once I logged out, or showed up on the community.
Someone please help, I love google+ very much and this is ruining my account.

Answer (score 1):

You might be sharing with the wrong circles.

When you create a post, make sure the "To" field is set to `Public` if you want anyone to be able to see your post.

Answer (score 1):

Your posts were caught in the spam filter. You can ask a moderator of a community (that's what I did and she managed to remove me) but I don't know how to do this by yourself. Here's a link she gave me on avoiding this in the future: [Possible reasons why G+ flags certain posts as spam](https://plus.google.com/+JohnSkeats/posts/R9y9VtUPxSh)

Credit to Micah Pascual for figuring this out for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Is your post not visible to anyone in the community except you? Aren’t you getting views and likes on posting in communities? If yes, then reason is you are sharing same content to several communities or links from a particular website, resulting in marking you as spam by G+ filters.
>
> Don’t worry this not any kind of ban or restriction. But it is a sign that you are violating G+ policies.

read more: http://www.matrudev.com/post/post-in-community-not-visible-anyone/
and
http://www.matrudev.com/post/big-mistakes-people-make-using-google-plus/

Comment: If you are affiliated with the blog, please disclose that in your answer.  Answering purely for the sake of posting the blog link is frowned upon.